# performance issue with std::normal_distribution?

Tags: c++, random, stl, stdvector, normal-distribution

One of the classes I use has a `data` member that is a `std::vector` of about 12 million numbers (`float` or `double`). If I just read it from file and write it, that takes much less than a second. But if I also add normally distributed noise using this function

```
void addNormalNoise ( double mu, double sigma ) {

std::random_device    randomdevice {};
std::mt19937 engine { randomdevice ()  };

std::normal_distribution <double> normaldist ( mu, sigma );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++ )
      data[i] += normaldist ( engine );

}
```

it takes almost 3 seconds to run. To me this is the simplest and most direct way of calling the `normaldist` function, but is this hopelessly inefficient in some way? What is causing the delay?

Comment: And just for completeness: did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: Please post your *exact* compiler options/flags. I'm guessing you are running an unoptimized debug build. Also; what's the size of `data`?

Comment: On my system it takes 712 ms to fill a vector with 12'000'000 doubles generated by an exponential distribution (default param). 674 ms to add random noise (default param). File I/O, 8745 ms to write to file, 7317 ms to read from file. This is using VC++ x64 Release build. Similar but slightly faster using MinGW -O3 except for read from file takes five times as long.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @uneven_mark, I expect file I/O to be much slower than CPU / memory operations. Others, indeed this was the Debug target. The difference with the Release target is huge! That runs under .3s. Feel free to 'answer' the question, otherwise I may delete the whole thing.